# Class 'Category' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\tg\system\core\Loader.php on line 303

Tags: sql

I have my xampp folder in c drive I can use MySQL and the admin and can do all the function related to db .. but I have a problem in running my folder i.e, tg the data where the website is present in.

When I try to run my website it gives me error:

`Fatal error:  Class 'Category' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\tg\system\core\Loader.php on line 303`

what can I do to reduce this? I have already on the short open tag and again try to open local host tg but i can not open it.

Comment: You need to show us code.  Without it we're shooting in the dark.

Comment: How is this related to [sql] when your problem is clearly a PHP problem, and to be more precise, you are NOT including the 'Category' class containing file in the Loader.php

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your base_url() in CodeIgniter/config/config.php ?

Look for

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_codeigniter_directory/';
```

and change it to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/your_codeigniter_directory/';
```

Your error shows that the application is still in xampp no?